# How to find the shortest path with the minimum number of hops in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Im modeling a graph where nodes are places and edges indicate that you can go from one place to another.

This is to have all routes that you can take from a place to another,
and you can go from a place to another by different routes, so I want a query that returns me the shortest path with the minimum route changes.

For example, I want to go from A to D, I have two possible paths:

```
(place {name: "A"})-[:FOLLOWS{route:""R1}]->(place{name: "B" })-[:FOLLOWS{route:""R4}]->(place{name:"C"})-[:FOLLOWS{route:""R2}]->(place{name:"D"})

(place {name: "A"})-[:FOLLOWS{route:""R1}]->(place{name: "B" })-[:FOLLOWS{route:""R1}]->(place{name:"F"})-[:FOLLOWS{route:""R2}]->(place{name:"D"})
```

In the previous two path, both are the same size,  but I would like to get the second one, which is the one who has the minimum route changes.

Thank you.

Comment: This was a great question and I learned a fair bit from the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will meet your needs. It finds all of the shortest paths.  Then it processes each one to count the number of route changes.  It then orders the result set by the fewest route changes and limits the result set to the first occurrence.

```
// find all of the shortest paths that match the beginning and ending nodes
match p=allShortestPaths((a:Place {name: 'A'})-[:FOLLOWS*]->(d:Place {name: 'D'}))

// carry forward the path, the relationships in the path and a range that represents the second to last relationships in the path 
with p,relationships(p) as rel, range(1,length(p)-1) as index

// use reduce to process the route attribute on the relationship to accumulate the changes
with p, rel, index, reduce (num_chg = 0, i in index | num_chg + 
    case when (rel[i]).route = (rel[i-1]).route then 0 else 1 end ) as changes

// return the path and the number of route changes
return p, changes

// only return the path with the fewest route change
order by changes
limit 1
```

Answer (score 4):

@DevBennett's answer gets the shortest path with the minimum number of *route changes*.

To get the shortest path with the minimum number of *different routes*, which is what the question literally asked for (but which may not have been what the asker actually wanted), you can use this query:

```
MATCH p=ALLSHORTESTPATHS((a:Place {name: "A"})-[:FOLLOWS*]->(d:Place{name:"D"}))
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rel 
WITH p, COUNT(DISTINCT rel.route) AS nRoutes 
RETURN p, nRoutes 
ORDER BY nRoutes 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I actually wanted the minimum number of route changes because in a path I can have 2 routes but in every edge make a change.
Anyway I realize that I made both questions :) Sorry for the misunderstood. This is really helpful too. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
MATCH 
    (a:place {name: "A"}) WITH a
MATCH
    (d:place {name: "D"}) WITH a,d 
MATCH
    p = allShortestPaths  ( (a)-[:FOLLOWS*..100]->(d) )
WITH 
    nodes(p) as places, relationships(p) as paths
UNWIND
    paths as path
WITH
    places, paths, collect(distinct path.route) as segments
RETURN
    places, paths, segments, size(segments) as cost
ORDER BY
    cost ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This works the way I wanted only if I change this:
p = allShortestPaths  ( (a)-[:FOLLOWS*]->(d) ).
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Come on, you could not be happy with only 3 answers :)

```
MATCH (a:Place {name:"A"}), (d:Place {name:"D"})
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((a)-[*]->(d))
RETURN p, 
size(filter(x in range(0, size(rels(p))) 
       WHERE (rels(p)[x]).route <> (rels(p)[x-1]).route)) + length(p) as score
ORDER BY score ASC
```

Comment: I like it - wish i had come up with that one.

Answer (score 0):

The answers using "AllShortestPaths" are wrong.

What if the graph looks like the image below?

[Example of Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYC6A.png)
Well, the result of the queries using AllShortestPaths function will be "A-E-D" and not "A-B-C-D" ...

Comment: Sorry, i've just signed in and i don't have enough "Reputation" to comment :p