# Neo4j limit a property value to only x changes

Tags: database, neo4j

Is there a way on Neo4J to say for a query like this

```
MATCH (p1:BusStop {idStop: "1293"}), (p2:BusStop {idStop: "1052"}),
  path = shortestpath((p1)-[:PATH*]->(p2))
RETURN path
```

That i want it to keep for all the path the same property value.

Something like :

```
MATCH (p1:BusStop {idStop: "1293"}), (p2:BusStop {idStop: "1052"}),
  path = shortestpath((p1)-[:PATH*{busLineID: AlwaysTheSame}]->(p2))
RETURN path
```

But i don't want to write the busLineID by myself because i can't know it in advance.

If this is possible is it also possible to say to neo4j : change the value of this property at most x times during the path ?

Thanks

Comment: Your :PATH relationship doesn't have a direction. Is that correct, or are you looking only for paths going TO p2?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, didn't have time to work on this project.
Yep, I'm looking only for paths going TO p2, just forgot the `>`, my bad :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a predicate to ensure that all relationships in the path have the same property value.

It helps to figure out all the possible busLineID values first by finding the values in common in relationships coming off of both nodes.

```
MATCH (p1:BusStop {idStop: "1293"})-[r:PATH]-()
WITH p1, COLLECT(DISTINCT r.busLineID) as firstSet
MATCH (p2:BusStop {idStop: "1052"})-[r:PATH]-()
WITH p1, p2, firstSet, COLLECT(DISTINCT r.busLineID) as secondSet
WITH p1, p2, FILTER(id IN firstSet WHERE id IN secondSet) as commonIDs
UNWIND commonIDs as busLineID
MATCH path = shortestpath((p1)-[:PATH*]-(p2))
WHERE ALL(rel in RELATIONSHIPS(path) | rel.busLineID = busLineID)
RETURN path
```

The advantage to knowing the values ahead of time is that the WHERE ALL clause can be evaluated as shortestPath() is being calculated, instead of applying the predicate as a filter after matching all possible paths, which is much slower.

Regarding your second question, about allowing the property value to change, and attempting to limit that change, that's extremely tricky, at least to my knowledge.

First, let's try something easier. We'll find all shortest paths first, and figure out how many route changes occur for each of those shortest paths, ordering by the path with the fewest changes. I'm going to borrow the approach in [one of Christophe Willemsen's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36585449/92359) for a rather similar problem (it's worth reviewing when you get the chance):

```
MATCH (p1:BusStop {idStop: "1293"}), (p2:BusStop {idStop: "1052"})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((p1)-[:PATH*]-(p2))
RETURN p, SIZE(FILTER(x in RANGE(0, SIZE(RELATIONSHIPS(p))) 
       WHERE (RELATIONSHIPS(p)[x]).busLineID <> (RELATIONSHIPS(p)[x-1]).busLineID)) as busLineChanges
ORDER BY busLineChanges ASC
```

But if you still want to return shortest paths allowing bus line switches within a limit I'm pretty sure you'll have to abandon using shortestPath() for this, as I don't believe the operations you need to do to figure out the number of distinct busLineID changes can be done in either the MATCH or the WHERE, it needs to be done in WITH or RETURN, which just won't work with shortestPath() (the shortestPath() MATCH and WHERE would execute first returning one shortest path, and more than likely your additional filtering in the rest of the query would filter out that single shortestPath() result).

You'll need to do it manually with a match on a variable-length relationship and filter down, and that path matching may span your entire graph.

I don't think it will be an efficient query, but I'll give it a try, and I highly encourage you to add an upper bound to your variable :PATH relationship (I'll add it in for now, change it up to what makes sense for you without causing the query to hang):

```
MATCH (p1:BusStop {idStop: "1293"}), (p2:BusStop {idStop: "1052"})
MATCH path = (p1)-[rels:PATH*1..10]-(p2)
WITH path, SIZE(FILTER(x in RANGE(0, SIZE(rels)) 
           WHERE (rels[x]).busLineID <> (rels[x-1]).busLineID)) as busLineChanges
WHERE busLineChanges <= 3
RETURN path, busLineChanges
ORDER BY SIZE(path) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I also encourage you to add direction to your :PATH relationships if possible, that may help path matching performance.